# HTML5 video tag not working on iOS, video not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, video

The following code works fine on desktop browser, but on my iPad, the video is not loaded.

Is there a problem in my code ?

HTML :

```
<video id="helpVideoPlayer" width="788" height="327" controls>
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

JS :

```
var videoUrl = "../video/test.mp4";
$("#helpVideoPlayer source").attr("src", videoUrl);
$("#helpVideoPlayer").load();
```

Comment: Did you add MIME types in your .htaccess/apache rules ?

Comment: Please have a look at this http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html, at the end into "MIME TYPES REAR THEIR UGLY HEAD" section

Comment: I just added `AddType video/mp4 .mp4` line in my httpd.conf and same result..

Comment: One common reason for this is the video format - can you post a link to the video so it ca be checked? See answer below for link to iOS formats (won't fit here).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, one common reason for this is the video format.

The apple guide to supported formats is here:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html

and this is relevant part:

> iOS supports many industry-standard video formats and compression standards, including the following:
>
> - H.264 video, up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - H.264 video, up to 768 Kbps, 320 by 240 pixels, 30 frames per second, Baseline Profile up to Level 1.3 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - MPEG-4 video, up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48 kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
> - Numerous audio formats, including the ones listed in Audio Technologies

Its worth understanding that MP4 is a 'container' specification for video and audio steams and the videos and audios in the container may use different encodings, so some mp4 files may be supported and others may not.

Answer (score -3):

```
<video id="helpVideoPlayer" controls="true" width="788" height="327" src="" type="video/mp4"

</video>
```

It will work fine on both ipad on iphone

Comment: <video id="helpVideoPlayer" width="788" height="327" controls="true">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>